# Define a matrix in python with unknown element

Tags: python

I've a Matrix with some unknown variables, that needed to be solved by a computer. How can I tackle this problem??

For eg - K = [[1,0],[0, (1-p)**.5]]  , where p is the unknown varable that needs to be found out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Solving Equations**
>
> SymPy's `solve()` function can be used to solve equations and expressions that contain symbolic math variables.
>
> Equations with one solution A simple equation that contains one
>   variable like  `x−4−2=0`  can be solved using the solve function. When
>   only one value is part of the solution, the solution is in the form of
>   a list.
>
> The code section below demonstrates SymPy's solve() function when an
>   expression is defined with symbolic math variables.

```
from sympy import symbols, solve

x = symbols('x')
expr = x-4-2

sol = solve(expr)

print (sol)
```

Output:

```
[6]
```

.

```
from sympy import symbols, solve
p = symbols('p')
expr = (1-p)**.5

sol = solve(expr)

print (sol)
```

output:

```
[1.00000000000000]
```

.

```
from sympy import symbols, solve

K = [[1,0],[0, int(solve((1-symbols('p'))**.5)[0])]]
print (K)
```

output:

```
[[1, 0], [0, 1]]
```